# how to display two records in a table row out of multiple total records in php?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have to display the SQL records (displayed in divs) in a table in which I can display only 2 records in one row. The total number of records i.e. n are not fixed and not an array too. The number of rows will depend on the number of records available. I tried couple of ways for instance defining "define('TABLE_COLS', 2);" and  using for loop inside my while loop but they didn't give me the required result. The code I am working on is as following:

```
    echo "<table>";
    $sql = "Some SQL";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    $num = mysql_numrows($result);
    $i = 0;
    define('TABLE_COLS', 2);

    echo "<tr>";
        while ($i < $num) {
        //  for($i=0; $i<=2; $i++){
                $name = mysql_result($result,$i,"name");
                $Count = mysql_result($result,$i,"count");                      
        //  echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>";
                    echo "<div>";
                        echo "<div>";
                            echo "$name";
                        echo "</div>";
                        echo "<div>";
                            echo "$Count";
                        echo "</div>";      
                    echo "</div>";
                echo "</td>";       
        //  echo "</tr>";
            $i++;
            }
    echo "</tr>";
    mysql_free_result($result);
echo "</table>";
```

The result I am looking for is like:
    Now I have to add count values of corresponding event id and display it in a result table as following. I am very new in PHP so please help me. Any comments much appreciated.

```
+------------+   +--------------+
|  Abby Bory |   |  Manny Mua   |
+------------+   +--------------+
|      4     |   |     22       |
+------------+   +--------------+
+------------+   +--------------+
|  Senyz Dory|   |  Kory Bua    |
+------------+   +--------------+
|      8     |   |     27       |
+------------+   +--------------+
```

Comment: is the number of columns changed dynamically?

Comment: @Woody: no, the number of rows change while keeping 2 records in every rows.

Comment: keeping 2 records in every rows mean columns do not change?

Comment: yes, the column doesn't change there should be only two columns but the number of rows is dynamic depending on the mysql records. I had edited my previous comment.

Comment: you can try my code below and fix the `$num_col` to `2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try if this help to solve your problem. I would declare multiple variables to make things easier to manage such as changing columns per row. The given code should adapt to any number of columns per row. Let me know if this is what you need.
Also, consider using `mysqli` instead of `mysql`.

Update 1: Include sample database format to standardize the format

**database.php**

```
<?php

$db_servername = "DATABASE SERVER NAME";
$db_username = "DATABASE USERNAME";
$db_password = "DATABASE PASSWORD";
$db_database = "DATABASE TABLE";

// Create connection
$con = new mysqli($db_servername, $db_username, $db_password, $db_database);

// Check connection
if ($con->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $con->connect_error);
}

?>
```

**Example Code**

```
require "database.php";

global $con;
echo "<table>";

$sql = "SOME SQL";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
// define number of columns per row
$num_col = 2; 
// calculate total number of row based on columns per row defined
$total_row = intVal(mysqli_num_rows($result) / $num_col);
// calculate left over result if the division result is not perfect number
$left_over = mysqli_num_rows($result) % $num_col;

$counter = 0;

while($counter < $total_row){
   echo '<tr>';
   for($i = 0; $i < $num_col; $i++){
       $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
       echo "<td>";
       echo "<div>".$row["name"]."</div>";
       echo "<div>".$row["count"]."</div>";
       echo "</td>";
   }
   echo '</tr>';
   $counter++;
}

echo "<tr>";
while($left_over > 0 ){
   $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
   echo "<td>";
   echo "<div>".$row["name"]."</div>";
   echo "<div>".$row["count"]."</div>";
   echo "</td>";
   $left_over--;
}
echo "</tr>";

echo "</table>";
```

Comment: For $con = "DEFINE YOUR DATABASE CONNECTION"; I had included my database connection from a different file which is at different location. so do you think i have to delete that include syntax and do DB connectivity on this page for calculating $leftover?

Comment: you can include your previously defined database file. `$leftover` should just work if you define your database file correctly

Comment: I added a sample database file in case you have issue defining the file.

Comment: It gives me some warnings "Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, resource given in  the line $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);" here $db is my connection variable. And also another warning" mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in the line: $total_row = intVal(mysqli_num_rows($result) / $num_col);" @Woody

Comment: can I take a look at your db file? you can try to define database file according to the format i posted

Comment: the `Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, resource given in the line $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);` could happen if your database connection is not using `mysqli` format

Answer (score 0):

This can give some ideas. definitely you must pay attention to the last record because in each iteration two records are read.

```
    echo "<table>";
    $sql = "Some SQL";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    $num = mysql_numrows($result);
    $i = 0;

    while ($i < $num) {
        $name1 = mysql_result($result,$i,"name");
        $Count1 = mysql_result($result,$i,"count");                      
        $name2 = mysql_result($result,$i+1,"name");
        $Count2 = mysql_result($result,$i+1,"count");                      
         echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>";
                    echo "$name1";
                echo "</td>";
                echo "<td>";
                    echo "$name2";
                echo "</td>";
          echo "</tr>";
          echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>";
                    echo "$count1";
                echo "</td>";
                echo "<td>";
                    echo "$count2";
                echo "</td>";
          echo "</tr>";

            $i+=2;
            }

    mysql_free_result($result);
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Thanks Mahmoud. Does this code refer only for 2 rows or multiple? as my rows can be more than 2.

Comment: I am asking this because it threw me warnings in the lines where there are "$name2 = mysql_result($result,$i+1,"name");
        $Count2 = mysql_result($result,$i+1,"count");"  The warnings are same for those lines and it is: "mysql_result():Unable to jump to row 3 on MySQL result index 6 "

Comment: this most probably because of invalid column names. it is better to use `mysql_fetch_array` instead of fetching values manually by yourself.

Comment: I added $name3 = mysql_result($result,$i+2,"name"); for third column it gave me same record (redundant record) at the end of a tr(row) and also in the beginning of next tr (row). Do you know why is that happening?

Comment: @VicStat does it give you redundant records at every row or just in the last one??? if it occure at every row, you must change `$i+=2;` to `$i+=3;` else may be it reached the end of dataset and give you the last one

Answer (score 0):

The simple is to do this is make it on div's with bootstrap css.

Like

```
foreach($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
   echo '<div class="col-sm-3">'.$row['name'].'<br />'.$row['count'].'</div>';
}
```

as you see "col-sm-3" will divide one row into four columns.
and "col-sm-6" will divide row into two columns.

col-sm-12 will be the will have one row with one column.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not using bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

Then try it,

```
echo "<table>";
$sql = "Some SQL";
$result = mysqli_query($sql);

$count = 0;
//No of columns per row    
$noColumns = 2;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    if( $count % $noColumns == 0){
        echo '<tr>';
    }
    echo '<td><div>'.$row['name'].'<br />'.$row['count'].'</div></td>';
    $count++;
    if( $count % $noColumns == 0){
        echo '</tr>';
    }
}
 if( $count % $noColumns != 0){
    //Close the last row
    $remainCols = $noColumns - ($count % $noColumns);
    echo '<td colspan="'.$remainCols.'">&nbsp;</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
 }
echo '</table>';
mysqli_free_result($result);
```

it is based calculation with Mod(%) operator. Hope it solves.
I have used mysqli as reference instead of mysql.

Answer (score 0):

This solution solved my problem.

```
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$num_col = 2; 
$total_row = intVal(mysql_num_rows($result) / $num_col);

$i = 0;

while($i < $total_row){
   echo '<tr>';
   for($i = 0; $i < $num_col; $i++){
       $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
       echo "<td>";
       echo "<div>".$row["name"]."</div>";
       echo "<div>".$row["count"]."</div>";
       echo "</td>";
   }
   echo '</tr>';
   $i++;
   }
```

Thanks to all who helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Hi this is the simplest answer i found, i went through several ways but failed, this is the right way

```
<table class="table" id="table">
            <?php for($loop = 0; $loop <= 7; $loop++) : ?>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="brand[]" value="<?php echo $loop; ?>"> Brand <?php echo $loop; ?>
                </td>
            <?php endfor; ?>
        </table>
```

dont use tr and in style do something like this

```
#table td {
width: 50%;
float: left;
```

}